# Why is this console error showing after this Vuex mutation commit?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, frontend, vuex

I'm quite new with Vue and Vuex, I'm having this console error after *committing a declared Mutation* in the store, which by the way, **besides from the console error is doing its job**. The error which is: `ReferenceError: ADD_EVENT is not defined at eval (EventCreate.vue?89e7:82:1)`, it's pretty much self-explanatory.
I'm probably missing one step or calling something in the wrong place but it all seems to be in place, so here's my code:
*the store:*

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex'

export default createStore({
  state: {
    user: 'TommyDemian',
    events: []
  },
  mutations: {
    ADD_EVENT(state, event){
      state.events.push(event);

    }
  },
  getters: {
  },
  actions: {
  },
  modules: {
  }
})
```

*The component committing the mutation:*

```
export default {
  name:'EventCreate',
  setup () {
    const store = useStore();

    const onSubmit = () => {
      event.organizer = store.state.user;
      event.id = uuidv4();
      apiClient.postEvent(event).then(() => {
        store.commit(ADD_EVENT, event);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
    };
  
      const event = reactive ({
        id: '',
        category: '',
        title: '',
        description: '',
        location: '',
        date: '',
        time: '',
        organizer: ''
      });

      return {
        onSubmit,
        categories,
        event,
        store,
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should dispatch [action](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html) which commit mutation:

```
actions: {
  setEvent({ commit }, event) {
    apiClient.postEvent(event)
      .then((response) => {
        commit('ADD_EVENT', response);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling a variable `ADD_EVENT`. Instead you should pass the string of your mutation method.

`store.commit("ADD_EVENT", event);`